# How to Use Nokia Imaging SDK Curves Filter

Tags: windows-phone-8, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

I am refencing a sample nokia project, and I would like to add the Curves filter. I am unsure of how to do this, as I do not understand what the Curve parameters are that are required by the filter

```
CurvesFilter(Curve red, curve Green, curve blue)
```

What do I need to insert into the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Just check documentation. It is described here:
[CurvesFilter](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Imaging_API_Ref/#!nokiagraphicsimaging-namespace/curvesfilter-class/curvesfilter-members.html)

***First** constructor creates and initializes a new CurvesFilter with default values:*

```
CurvesFilter()
```

***Second** constructor creates and initializes a new CurvesFilter with a set of color curves:*

```
CurvesFilter(Curve, Curve, Curve)
```

So red, green and blue is type of **Curve** class. You can check documentation here: [Curve](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Imaging_API_Ref/#!nokiagraphicsimaging-namespace/curve-class/curve-members.html)

So you should create a new object of the class:

```
Curve(CurveInterpolation)
```

**CurveInterpolation** is the mode of interpolation between points.

Comment: I see there is `CurveInterpolation.Linear` and `CurveInterpolation.NaturalCubicSpline` but how do I insert these into the `CurvesFilter`?

Comment: CurveInterpolation is property so use "." notation. I don't have this SDK so I can't test.Try like var red = new Curve(CurveInterpolation.Linear);

Comment: Don't forget to add some points to the Curve after creating it!

Comment: Could you give an example please? I've done `var red = new Curve(CurveInterpolation.Linear);
                red.SetPoint(0, 0);` but I'm not sure what to do with this?

Comment: @Matthew After creating the curves, you create a curves filter, and you add that to your FilterEffect's Filters list. You then render your chain.